# Как симулировать onpointermove?

Tags: typescript, юнит-тесты, jest

метод класса View

```
private beginSliding(event: PointerEvent): HTMLElement {
  const { pointerId } = event;
  const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
  event.preventDefault();
  target.setPointerCapture(pointerId);

  target.onpointermove = (e: PointerEvent) => {
    // Uncovered Line #s
    let thumbName: ThumbName = 'to';

    if (target.classList.contains('range-slider__thumb_from')) {
      thumbName = 'from';
    } else if (target.classList.contains('range-slider__thumb_to')) {
      thumbName = 'to';
    }

    const currentPos = this.getPosOnScale(this.currentCursorPosition(e));
    this.setMargins(thumbName, currentPos);
    this.updateRangeSliderValues();
    this.setDistanceBetweenTooltips();
    // Uncovered Line #s
  };
  return target;
}
```

тест

```
it('private beginSliding', () => {
  const moveEvent = new PointerEvent('pointermove', {
    pointerId: 1,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: 150,
    clientY: 150,
    pointerType: 'touch',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    tangentialPressure: 0,
    tiltX: 0,
    tiltY: 0,
    isPrimary: true,
  });

  Element.prototype.setPointerCapture = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(undefined);

  const view = new View('range-slider', settings);
  const setMarginsSpy = jest.spyOn(view, 'setMargins');

  view.to.element.dispatchEvent(moveEvent);
  const result = view['beginSliding'](moveEvent);

  expect(result.onpointermove).not.toBeNull();
  expect(setMarginsSpy).toBeCalled(); // тест не проходит
});
```

тест не проходит потому что функция в target.onpointermove не выполняется, при этом предыдущий тест проходит и это показывает что onpointermove != null

ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]